# Converting character to numeric and then back to character

Tags: r

I would like to know if it is possible in R to convert a vector of characters to numerical values, and then convert those numerical values back to their original characters?

For example, my code is:

```
data <- c("red","blue","green","red","yellow")
factor_data <- factor(data)
num_data <- as.numeric(factor_data)
print(num_data)
```

I would get

```
3 1 2 3 4
```

where blue = 1, green = 2, red = 3, yellow = 4

is there a way I can use `num_data` and get the corresponding character of colors to it?

My attempt was the code:

```
(factor_data)[num_data]
```

but that just returned me:

```
green red blue  green red
```

which is not the same as the original vector of colors.

Comment: `as.character(factor_data)`? ...or are you looking for something like `setNames(as.integer(factor(data)), data)`?

Comment: I am trying to use num_data to try and get back the colors. So if I were to have a random vector of integers from 1 to 4, i can change that vector of integers into a vector of corresponding colors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the factor's levels to effectively revert back to the original character vector.

```
levels(factor_data)[num_data]
# [1] "red"    "blue"   "green"  "red"    "yellow"
```

Data from the question:

```
data <- c("red","blue","green","red","yellow")
factor_data <- factor(data)
num_data <- as.numeric(factor_data)
```